# jquery draggable prevent firing selectable using click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to combine the lovely couple of JQueryUI's draggable and selectable ;)

What I'm trying to do:

- Divs could be selected using click. That would be displayed by applying... maybe css border/shadow to selected div. Just to highlight it.
- The same divs could be dragged using JQueryUI's draggable.

using a portion of [ryan coughlin's code](http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/23/combining-selectables-and-draggables-using-jquery-ui/), I made this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/rYgXE/

Mostly okay. The problem is, The divs could no longer be highlighted (css shadow in this case) using CLICK. only DRAG trigger highlight to the divs. [The running sample of ryan coughlin's code](http://jsfiddle.net/PDPZx/) also couldn't be selected (highlighted) using click.

I don't really understand what happen, but it seems that draggable code prevent selectable code from working.

any solution/idea?

thx :D

Comment: I'm trying not to. Actually I don't know whether selectable would benefit me more (in the future) than a simple click event.

Comment: See my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419263/propagation-issue-in-nested-jquery-ui-selectable/46819120#46819120

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to add this function

```
$(".selectable div").click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("ui-selected")) {
        $(this).addClass("ui-selected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
    }
})
```

here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rYgXE/2/

Comment: oww ok then. i'm not used with manners in stackoverflow except the general thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:
The JQuery **Selectable** script not only binds mouse click but also the mouseDrag.
We can use the selectable script to select multiple items by dragging your mouse to that other item.(see [demo example](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Selectable) and drag your mouse)

The **draggable** script is to drag an item(or)element in the page.
Now, when you added draggable script... which also captures the mouseclick(to determine relative position) and mousedrag(to drag the item) events is clashing with the script in selectable...

Solution:
If your problem is to just highlight the element your are dragging you can achieve that by writing a simple javascript function to select as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/rYgXE/6/

Comment: I disable the _mouseDrag part of selectable in jqueryui.js file. I hope to have click from selectable and drag from draggable. Doesn't work though. Hmm I think everyone is right, simple click would do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue #8106 in jquery ui. The work around is to use the lasso (ie select a box outside the element and cover it with the box)

Some see this as a feature instead of a problem

Bug report at https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8106).

Another work around, if you only want limited selectability (like me) is to not use the jquery selectable but add this js to any divs you want to select. It works by firing when the jquery resize icon is clicked:

```
$("#"+id+">.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se").click(function(ev){
                    $(".ui-selected").removeClass("ui-selected");
                    $(this).parent().addClass("ui-selected");
                });
```

with css like:

```
div.ui-selected {border: 1px solid red;}
```